# Imagemagick - "insufficient image data in file" error open from google cloud storage

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, imagemagick

I'm writing a PHP script to do some analysis of files we have stored in
Google Cloud storage, and am running into problems - every file throws
an "insufficient image data in file" exception:

```
$imagick = new Imagick();

// Initialize GoogleCloudStorage access
$google_client_config = [
    'projectId'   => MY_PROJECT_ID,
    'keyFilePath' => MY_SERVICE_KEY_PATH
];

// get access to the bucket for object access, and enable the wrapper
$storage_client = new StorageClient( $google_client_config );

// allow reading with fopen, etc from 'gs://' scheme
$storage_client->registerStreamWrapper();

$bucket = $storage_client->bucket( MY_BUCKET_NAME );
$bucket_path = gs://PATH_TO_MY_BUCKET

$mls_id ='MT-NWMAR';
$params = [
    'prefix' => $mls_id,
    'fields' => 'items/id,items/name,items/updated,nextPageToken',
];

$objects = $bucket->objects($params);
foreach ($objects as $object ) {
    if ( substr( $object->name(), -4 ) != '.jpg') continue;

    $full_file_path = "$bucket_path/" . $object->name();

    $imagick->clear();  // clear IM internals
    try {
        $imagick->readImage( $full_file_path );
    }
    catch ( Exception $ex ) {
        print "Exception for $full_file_path: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
}
```

This throws exceptions for every file in the bucket:

```
Exception for gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME/MT-NWMAR/30006995/org/032.jpg: insufficient image data in file `/tmp/magick-25748xWZCfvQg3MVj' @ error/jpeg.c/ReadJPEGImage/1117
```

I can use gsutil to copy the file to my local machine, and identify works fine there:

```
gsutil cp gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME/MT-NWMAR/30006995/org/032.jpg .
identify 032.jpg 
032.jpg JPEG 1920x1080 1920x1080+0+0 8-bit sRGB 694478B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Not sure why - I suspect maybe the wrapper isn't pulling the whole file in?

running:

```
php v8.0.18

ImageMagick: 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64
```

Comment: Using `gsutil` to copy the file over to run identify on it is different from trying to run identify directly on the cloud location without downloading it.  Not sure readImage can access files directly using `gs://`.  Try it to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$imagick->readImage( $full_file_path );` expects a local filename. The scheme `gs://` is not supported.

Use the storage SDK to download the object and then load it into Image Magick.

Comment: Well, I was hoping for a better answer - going through thousands of images manually downloading and then processing will likely be too heavy a lift for this process. Thanks all.